# Append div and scroll to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I need to add a new `div` at the end of the existing ones in parent `div` and scroll to the right in order to see always the last add ones.

However, all my tries using `jQuery` `scrollLeft` have failed (note: use `jQuery` is not mandatory, in particular, solutions without it are welcome).

This is the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>    
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
        <title>list1b</title>    
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style>    
            #results {
                font-size: 500%;
                display: flex;
                height: 4cm;
                align-items: center;
                overflow: auto;
            }    
        </style>

        <script>    
            var formula1 = "1 + 2x";
            var formula2 = "= 1 + 2y";

            var appendDiv = function (f) {
                var newDiv = $("<div style='min-width:10cm;'>" + f + ·</div>"); // this div is an example
                var dstDiv = $('#results');
                dstDiv.append(newDiv);
                //dstDiv.scrollLeft(???);
            }    

            setTimeout(function () {
                appendDiv(formula1);
            }, 2000);

            window.changeIt = function () {
                appendDiv(formula2);
            }    
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="results" class="results"></div>

        <button onclick='changeIt()'/>click me</button>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Basically, it gets the `scrollWidth` and subtracts the attributes and scrolls left that much. Let me know if this works for you.

You need to use `$('#results')[0]` when getting the `scrollWidth` because `[0]` return the `JavaScript` version of an element whereas `$('#results')` returns the `jQuery` version. `scrollWidth` is a `JavaScript` property and `width()` is a `jQuery` function.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>list1b</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            #results {
            font-size: 500%;
            display: flex;
            height: 4cm;
            align-items: center;
            overflow: auto;
        </style>

        <script>
            var formula1 = "1 + 2x";
            var formula2 = "= 1 + 2y";

            var appendDiv = function (f) {
                var newDiv = $("<div style='min-width:10cm;'>" + f + "</div>"); // this div is an example
                var dstDiv = $('#results');
                dstDiv.append(newDiv);
                var left = $("#results")[0].scrollWidth - $("#results").width();
                $('#results').scrollLeft(left);
            }

            setTimeout(function () {
                appendDiv(formula1);
            }, 2000);

            window.changeIt = function() {
                appendDiv(formula2);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="results" class="results"></div>

        <button onclick='changeIt()'/>click me</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does the trick. Please, could you add two clarifications? why is need write "dstDiv[0].scrollWidth" instead of ""dstDiv.scrollWidth" without the "[0]"; and why use "dstDiv.width()" instead of "dstDiv[0].clientWidth".

Comment: Yes, I will add that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is something that is missing in your code to get it working, you need to make the calculation to get the value of `scrollLeft` property (the `scrollWidth` property minus the `width` of the container). This example will help you to understand how it works:

**HTML Code:**

```
<button id="add">Add div</button>
<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
#container {
    font-size: 0;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 500px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#container div {
    background: #F00;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;      
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
}
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
var cont = $("#container");
var button = $("#add");

button.on("click", function () {

    cont.append("<div>" + (cont.find("div").length + 1) + "</div>");

    scrollContainer();

});

function scrollContainer() {

    var available = cont[0].scrollWidth - cont.width();

    cont.animate({scrollLeft: available}, 500);

}

scrollContainer();
```

[Here you have a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/m93bkvf8/) with an example of the code.